# Simplification of square root of sum

Tags: python, sympy, square-root, simplification

Using SymPy, can I automatically simplify something like this:

```
sqrt(a**2 + 2ab + b**2)
```

to:

```
[(a+b), -(a+b)]?
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you want to do it programmatically, meaning a user writes `"sqrt(a**2 + 2ab + b**2)"` and your get out `"[(a+b), -(a+b)]"` through some kind of eval? It's a bit unclear what you want to do.

Comment: I look for a kind of simplification function: `simplify(sqrt(a**2 + 2ab + b**2))`

Comment: If a, b are positive. Something like this ``sqrt(a**2 + 2*a*b + b**2).combsimp().powsimp()`` will give ``(a + b)``. @mrk

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
>>> var('a b',positive=True)
(a, b)
>>> solve(x**2-(a**2 + 2*a*b + b**2), x)
[-a - b, a + b]
```